# Multiple Charts using ngFor with angular apexcharts

Tags: angular, charts, apexcharts

I am implementing apexcharts for **angular** from [here](https://apexcharts.com/angular-chart-demos/).
I could successfully work with charts and get desired results(for single or multiple charts) only if the charts are not rendered dynamically.

For EG -
**Chart 1 on same page**

```
                    <div id="chart" class="card-img-top">
                        <apx-chart [series]="chartOptions.series" [chart]="chartOptions.chart"
                            [colors]="chartOptions.colors" [labels]="chartOptions.labels"
                            [responsive]="chartOptions.responsive"></apx-chart>
                    </div>
```

**Chart 2 on the same page**

```
                    <div id="charttest" class="card-img-top">
                        <apx-chart [series]="chartOptions.testseries" [chart]="chartOptions.chart"
                            [colors]="chartOptions.colors" [labels]="chartOptions.labels"
                            [responsive]="chartOptions.responsive"></apx-chart>
                    </div>
```

As it can been seen that to render multiple charts, the **id** and **[series]** needs to different.

I am having no problem in rendering multiple charts if and only if it is not dynamic, i.e when I know upfront how many charts needs to be displayed.

The problem I am facing is that ***rendering of multiple charts dynamically, i.e when I do not know how many charts needs to be displayed based on some values from API. Basically something like***

```
            <div id="chart[x]"></div>
```

***inside a loop.***

For EG - Suppose we have x users and for every x users we have some data. Those needed to be displayed in charts. Now x is dynamic, so when new users gets added, I need to create the chart for new user.

FYI, I am **not limited to in using apexcharts for angular**, **any chart library would do** as long as it is **in angular**.

Help would be much appreciated

Comment: I dont understand the problem with using a `ngFor` loop

Comment: can you show us the error ?

Comment: There are no errors. I am wondering how to go about this

Comment: I’m looking at doing the same, did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by for loop with the help of assigning the series data to your looping element.

Let's see it briefly :

**1. In your type alias add an optional series property**

> ```
> export type AssessmentStatus = {
>   id: string;
>   status: string;
>   starttime: number;
>   mile: {
>     m: number;
>     i: number;
>     l: number;
>     e: number;
>   };
>   series?: Array<{ // This is the way i added for Pie Chart
>     name: string;
>     data: number[];
>     color: string;
>   }>;
> };
> ```

**2. Assign the series to each element whenever you want**

> ```
> this.assessmentStatus.forEach((item) => {
>        item.series = [
>          {
>            name: "Series",
>            data: Object.values(item.mile),
>            color: "#8B9EE3",
>          },
>        ];
> });
> ```

**3. Now in your template use this assigned series**

> ```
> <fuse-card
>      class="flex flex-col shrink-0 w-[200px] min-w-[200px] mr-2"
>      *ngFor="let item of assessmentStatus; index as i"
> >
>      <apx-chart
>         class="w-full min-w-full"
>         [series]="item.series" // This is the key point which property binds the series so once it gets assigned then each graph will have different series 
>         [chart]="chartOptions.chart"
>         [xaxis]="chartOptions.xaxis"
>         [plotOptions]="chartOptions.plotOptions"
>         [yaxis]="chartOptions.yaxis"
>         [tooltip]="chartOptions.tooltip"
>      ></apx-chart>
> </fuse-card>
> ```

Hope this will help you or somebody else. Thanks!

Happy Coding :-)